# What is the difference between usage of '/' and '\'?

Tags: magento2, xml, class

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test"
               template="test/example.phtml" />
```

In above example for class used '\' and template '/'

```
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER = "trans_email/ident_custom2/email";
```

Again we used both.
So when to use '/' and '\'?

Answer (score 0):

> const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER = "trans_email/ident_custom2/email";

Magento store data of configuration as '/' format.

Regarding '\' , it's PHP format.